# Convert Pandas series containing string to boolean

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, type-conversion, series

I have a DataFrame named `df` as

```
  Order Number       Status
1         1668  Undelivered
2        19771  Undelivered
3    100032108  Undelivered
4         2229    Delivered
5        00056  Undelivered
```

I would like to convert the `Status` column to boolean (`True` when Status is Delivered and `False` when Status is Undelivered)
but if Status is neither 'Undelivered' neither 'Delivered' it should be considered as `NotANumber` or something like that.

I would like to use a dict

```
d = {
  'Delivered': True,
  'Undelivered': False
}
```

so I could easily add other string which could be either considered as `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can just use `map`:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'Status':['Delivered', 'Delivered', 'Undelivered',
                                     'SomethingElse']})

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
          Status
0      Delivered
1      Delivered
2    Undelivered
3  SomethingElse

In [9]: d = {'Delivered': True, 'Undelivered': False}

In [10]: df['Status'].map(d)
Out[10]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3      NaN
Name: Status, dtype: object
```

Comment: im getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map'`.

Comment: `map` is a method on the Series, not DataFrame.

Comment: yea got it, sorry for that.

Answer (score 19):

An example of `replace` method to replace values only in the specified column `C2` and get result as `DataFrame` type.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'], 'C2':['Y', 'Y', 'X', 'X']})

  C1 C2
0  X  Y
1  Y  Y
2  X  X
3  Y  X

df.replace({'C2': {'X': True, 'Y': False}})

  C1     C2
0  X  False
1  Y  False
2  X   True
3  Y   True
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 15):

*Expanding on the previous answers:*

### Map method explained:

- *Pandas will lookup each row's value in the corresponding `d` dictionary, replacing any found keys with values from `d`.*
- *Values without keys in `d` will be set as `NaN`. This can be corrected with `fillna()` methods.*
- *Does not work on multiple columns, since pandas operates through serialization of `pd.Series` here.*
- Documentation: [pd.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
d = {'Delivered': True, 'Undelivered': False}
df["Status"].map(d)
```

### Replace method explained:

- *Pandas will lookup each row's value in the corresponding `d` dictionary, **and attempt** to replace any found keys with values from `d`.*
- *Values without keys in `d` will be be retained.*
- *Works with single and multiple columns (`pd.Series` or `pd.DataFrame` objects).*
- Documentation: [pd.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
d = {'Delivered': True, 'Undelivered': False}
df["Status"].replace(d)
```

---

Overall, **the replace method is more robust** and allows finer control over how data is mapped + how to handle missing or nan values.

Answer (score 7):

You've got everything you need. You'll be happy to discover [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html):

```
df.replace(d)
```

Comment: Ah, I only see it now I posted my answer. Is there a difference with `map` in this case?

Comment: It seems that something else (not in the dift) is just left with `replace`, but converted to `NaN` with `map`

Comment: I think ``map`` is a better choice here, actually, because if a value isn't in ``d`` then the value is invalid and should be replaced with ``NaN``.

Comment: `replace` seems to apply to DataFrame not to a Serie

Comment: It applies to both. My link was to the DataFrame documentation; here's one for Series. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html