# pandas convert strings column to boolean

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, boolean

I am trying to convert a column containing True/False and null values in string format to Boolean. But whatever I do I end up with either all True values or False Below is my approach to

consider following dataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':['True', np.nan, 'False'
                        'True', np.nan, 'False']})
```

```
df['w'].dtypes
Out: dtype('O')

df['w'].unique()
Out: array([True, nan, False], dtype=object)

d = {'nan': np.nan,'False':False, 'True': True}
df['w']=df['w'].map(d)

df['w'].dtypes
Out: dtype('O')

df['w'].unique()
array([nan], dtype=object)
```

One other approach I used is following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702272/convert-pandas-series-containing-string-to-boolean) SO post:

```
d = {'nan': 0,'False':0, 'True': 1 }
df['w']=df['w'].map(d)
df['w']=df['w'].astype('bool')
```

Now it turns to bool but converts all values to True

```
df['w'].dtypes
Out: dtype('bool')

df['w'].unique()
Out: array([ True])
```

What am I doing wrong?
I want all null values to be null

Comment: Can you share all relevant code and data? See: [mcve].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile what more can i share i have added code to generate my dataframe as well

Comment: That first approach (the map) looks correct to me, no?What’s wrong with it?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile it worked well, I was a little confused about nan being in their which resulted in `dtypes` out to be object, @jezrael ans/explanation helped clear the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think not necessary, because your original data contains boolean with `nan`s, dtypes is `object` because mixed values - boolean with missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':['True', np.nan, 'False']})

print (df['w'].unique())
['True' nan 'False']

print ([type(x) for x in df['w'].unique()])
[<class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>]
```

If also `nan` is string then your solution working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':['True', 'nan', 'False']})

print ([type(x) for x in df['w'].unique()])
[<class 'str'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'str'>]

d = {'nan': np.nan,'False':False, 'True': True}
df['w'] = df['w'].map(d)

print (df['w'].unique())
[True nan False]

print ([type(x) for x in df['w'].unique()])
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'bool'>]
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'w':[True, np.nan, False]})

print (df['w'].unique())
[True nan False]

print ([type(x) for x in df['w'].unique()])
[<class 'bool'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'bool'>]
```

If want replace `nan` to `False` use [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df['w'] = df['w'].fillna(False)
print (df)
       w
0   True
1  False
2  False

print (df['w'].dtypes)
bool

print (df['w'].unique())
[ True False]
```

Comment: if i want nan to be false as well then what should be the process?

Comment: Then use `df['w'] = df['w'].fillna(False)`