# Checking rows value and updating corresponding value within a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am having some issues to change values in a column. My dataset has the following columns

```
Index(['Date', 'Name', 'Surname', 'Verified Account', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3',
       'Col4', 'Col5'],
      dtype='object')
```

`'Verified Account', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3','Col4', 'Col5'` have rows with value `'True'/'False'`.
Right now `'Verified Account'` is based only on values from `Col1`. I would like to update it including all the other columns, i.e.:

`if 'Col1' or 'Col2' or 'Col3' or 'Col4' or 'Col5'` have values `'True'`, then `'Verified Account'` has value `'True'`
else `'Verified Account'` has value `'False'`.

I have tried with:

```
df['Verified Account'] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if df['Col1']=='True' or df['Col2']== 'True' or df['Col3']=='True' or df['Col4']== 'True' or df['Col5']=='True' else 'False')
```

but I have got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [bool] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw 3 points:

- First, you need to care about the ***types***. Here, the data seems to be string. *Is it the desired type* ? That doesn't seem since you'r in stringe manipulating *boolean* in *string*. The first step is maybe to convert this columns to *boolean*. This [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702272/convert-pandas-series-containing-string-to-boolean) explains how. You can try for the following for all these columns:

```
df['column_name'].map({"True": True, "False": False})
```

- The second point is that you're using a `apply` with a `lambda` function. But the problem is that you're not using the `x` value inside but the whole `df`. So you need to replace all the `df` variable with the `x` variable. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/apply-and-lambda-usage-in-pandas-b13a1ea037f7) is some reading about `apply` and `lambda`.
- The last point is that the [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function has an argument `axis` to know how to iterate : over columns or over rows. By default, it's over columns. But here, obviously, the operation needs to be performed over row. So `axis=1` is required.

The snippet becomes:

```
df['Verified Account'] = df.apply(lambda x: True if x['Col1']==True or x['Col2']== True or x['Col3']==True or x['Col4']== True or x['Col5']==True else False)
```

---

**Further improvement**:

- The `lambda` might be simplified by returning only the if condition

```
df['Verified Account'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Col1']== True or 
                                            x['Col2']== True or 
                                            x['Col3']== True or
                                            x['Col4']== True or 
                                            x['Col5']==True)
```

- There are more efficient way to perform this. The [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) has been design for. Don't forget to precise the axis used, here the row (e.g. `axis=1`). You can try:

```
df['Verified Account'] = df[["Col1", "Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"]].any(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do

```
df['Verfied Account']=df[['col1'...]].any(1)
```